# How do I break the broom in Untitled Goose Game?

Tags: untitled-goose-game

In *[Untitled Goose Game](https://goose.game)*, the second area (with the shops) has the To-Do list item to break the broom that the shopkeeper is holding. How do I do that? I've tried dragging it underneath the garage door area and then trying to close it on it, but that didn't work. I've also dragged it over to the phone booth and tried to close that door on it, but that didn't work either.

How do I break the broom?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

When the shopkeeper who owns the broom has spotted you in her shop area, she will try to use it to shoo you away. When that happens, you can grab the bottom of the broom while it's still in her hands. If you move away from her while doing this, the broom will break.

Comment: Wow, I hadn't realized that playing tug-of-war was the simple solution! Here I am trying to drag it all around into doors!

Comment: @Thunderforge I did the same thing for a while. "maybe if I jam it under this table.."

Comment: I think the main issue is the word "break".  I think about a permanent break in the handle, not just "pulling the head off", which is an easy fix.

Comment: @JPhi1618 Yeah, I'm with you. Full disclosure, I did this entirely on accident after trying everything listed in the question. There's no way I would've actually thought this through and figured it out.